# how to hide sorting icon from DataTables header at first time

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I want to hide datatable sorting icon first time on load , when ever I click on datatable's header icon will be display automatically.

I am not able to find solution of that

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's easily possible. But it's a good question non less if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just **remove sorting class** from datatable on **initComplete** that is

> sorting_asc 
>   sorting

Ex.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Datatable for search and sorting
    var table = $('.table').DataTable({
        "fixedHeader": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,

        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
            this.api().columns().header().each(function (th) {
                $(th).removeClass("sorting_asc");
                $(th).removeClass("sorting");
            }
         )
        },
    });
```

That is first time disable all sorting icon from table, after click on header it will allow sorting and show all icon

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in pure CSS. The icon appearances is based on classes injected by the plugin, not some CSS logic. But you can add an overruling class definition to each header:

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting_pre {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns().header().each(function(th) {
      $(th).addClass('sorting_pre')
    })
  }
})
```

and then remove that class *first* time the user is ordering / sorting the table:

```
table.one('order.dt', function() {
  table.columns().header().each(function(th) {
    $(th).removeClass('sorting_pre')
  })
})
```

as in this demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wvo98420/**

**Note**: This solution is targeting DT latest / 1.10.19. When using styling plugins (i.e bootstrap and so on) different steps may be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jquery.

assuming structure is

```js
    $('.header').on('click',function(){
       $('.icons').removeClass('hide-class');
    });
```

```css
 .hide-class{
       display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
      <ul>header (click here)
        <li class="icons hide-class">Name</li>
        <li class="icons hide-class">Address</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know mechanism , that how can I archive it  , but i am not able to get that datatable sorting icon ,if I get it once I can do anything on it